# how can i store data in groovy application as (session,flash) in web application

Tags: java, groovy

i have a groovy application, i want to store a value to re use it in another form
(as me.tag in vb.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an expando class that can store data in it as session 
for example:

```
    imports groovy.util.Expando;
    ....
    Expando session
    int counter = 0;
    ....
    session.counter = counter;
```